# How to create a folder with a .txt file inside using assembly language?

Tags: assembly, dosbox

I am trying to create a folder, then create a .txt file inside. It creates both the folder and the .txt file but it is outside the folder. The program is also not being terminated properly because Dos box crashes after I enter the input.

Here is my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
        buff db 30                                              ; allow 30 characters on string
        total db 0
        char db 30 dup (0)                                  ; array, 30 duplicates of 0 (0,0...)
        x db "Input a string: $"
        y db 10, 13, "SUCCESS!$"
        z db 10, 13,  "FAILED!$"

        a  db  "File.txt", 0
        b dw  ?
        d db "Hello world!$"

.code

main    proc near
        mov ax, @data          
        mov ds, ax      

        call prompt
        call input
        call cfolder
        call ctext

        int 20h
main    endp

prompt  proc near
        mov dx, offset x                    ; print x
        mov ah, 9                           ; accept string
        int 21h
        ret
prompt  endp

input   proc near
        mov dx, offset buff                 
        mov ah, 0ah                         ; buffered input
        int 21h
        ret
input endp

cfolder proc near
        mov bh, 0                               ; keyboard input
        mov bl, total                           
        add bx, offset char
        mov byte ptr [bx], 0
        mov dx, offset char             ; char = filepath
        mov ah, 39h                         ; make directory
        int 21h  
        jnc succ
        jc fail
        ret
cfolder endp

ctext   proc near

        mov ah,3ch
        mov cx,0
        mov dx, offset a
        int 21h
        jc fail                    

        mov b, ax

        mov ah,40h
        mov bx, b
        mov dx, offset d
        mov cx, 12                 ; no. of characters
        int 21h
        jc fail
        ret
ctext   endp

succ    proc near
        mov dx, offset y                    ; displays SUCCESS!
        mov ah,9
        int 21h   
        ret   
succ    endp

fail    proc near
        mov dx, offset z                    ; displays FAILED!
        mov ah,9
        int 21h  
        ret  
fail    endp

end main
```

Can you help me in finding the errors and replacing it with the right one?

Comment: you need to cd into the directory, before you create the file: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-3b.html. and instead of `INT 20` to quit to dos, use http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-4c.html

Comment: @Tommylee2k It worked! Thank you! ^^